# Decode JSON in Swift "The given data was not valid JSON."

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, http

I'm writing a swift program and I need to use an API to get the response.
Here is the API url:  http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
document: http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html

When I test it on terminal, it works well:
//command in terminal

curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/

//what I got

{"probability": {"neg": 0.30135019761690551, "neutral": 0.27119050546800266, "pos": 0.69864980238309449}, "label": "pos"}

But when I want to decode the response data in Swift, it failed.

My codes are attached as following:

```
struct Result : Codable{
    var probability: Probability
    var label: String
    struct Probability: Codable{
        var neg: Double
        var neutral: Double
        var pos: Double
    }
}
```

```
class ResponseData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var result: [Result] = []
    func API()-> Bool{
        guard let url = URL(string: "http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("text=great", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                print(error)
            } else {
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                print(httpResponse)
                guard let data = data else { return }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let decodedResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data)
                    self.result = [decodedResult]
                    print(self.result)
                        } catch let error {
                            print("Error decoding: ", error)
                    }
                }
            }
        })

        dataTask.resume()
        return true
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Error decoding:  dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0})))
```

I have searched a lot but could not find an available solution. Could anyone share some idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Print what you really receive: `print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`

Comment: But i'm not sure that the data is in the header. it should be instead in the body in a POST: `request.setValue("text=great", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` -> `request.httpBody = Data("text=great".utf8)`. Else in the `cURL`, it would have been behind the `-h` parameter, not the `-d`.

Comment: "The given data was not valid JSON". You need to review the Data by converting it to a string and see if it's malformed or has invalid syntax. 
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    print(string)

Comment: Note Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" 
 in your `Info.plist` to allow `http` connection to the server. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, I have set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" in your Info.plist to allow http connection. Thanks for reminding : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to identify where lies your issue:

So let's print what you in fact receive:

```
print("Data Str: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
```

That gives:

```
$> Data Str: Optional("Form Validation Errors\ntext: This field is required.\n")
```

So your JSON Decoding files because you didn't receive the expected output, it's not even JSON.

Now, let's see the working cURL Sample:

```
curl -d "text=great" http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/
```

The `-d` is for `httpBody`, not as your write for headers. If that were the case, you would have `-H 'Content-Type: text=great'`. Yours doesn't make sense at all, as what means "Content-Type" parameter in requests.

So, the request creation should be:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpBody = Data("text=great".utf8)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

Comment: You explain so clearly! Thanks for your patience. Your reply fully solve my puzzle. Thank you so much : )

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting invalid request.

```
request.setValue("text=great", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

is not correct, you have to send it as body in form-url-encoded

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = Data("text=great".utf8)
```

Comment: It helps! Thnaks~